# license key issue of BlinkID(React-Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application, scanning, blinkid

I have created an account on microblink.com as a developer and I have gotten a Licenses key after creating a free trial on BlinkID(react-native) project. And I have cloned your GitHub repo of [BlinkID/blinkid-react-native](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-react-native) and I have updated the android and ios License keys. After updated I run it run but after opening the scanning window it shows an error and it's a license-related error. I need to know about to store package name(Android).

[image]

```
const licenseKey = Platform.select({
    // iOS license key for applicationID: com.microblink.sample ----> instead of IDScanning
    ios: 'here is ios License key',
    // android license key for applicationID: com.microblink.sample ----> instead of IDScanning
    android: 'here is android License key'
})
```

I mean where I should type the package name. Please concern m with my question.

**N.B:** Please concern about the error attached file. **Advanced Thanks**!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the name of the package in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` files as well as in `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java` so it matches the appID you've generated the license with.